# how to run program on a remote pc without install

Tags: windows-10

Is it possible to run a program that is installed on my computer on a remote computer without installing that program on the remote computer.
I am using windows 10.
Do programs like team viewer do this sort of thing and if so how ?
thank you.

Comment: Have you tried?  You can run the program on the remote computer but not the client computer.....

Answer (score 0):

It depends on the application.

In general an installed windows application may run on another system but it is very likely that not all features are available or the program may behave buggy. That is because most applications during installation check dependencies, add registry entries and generate program specific files.

Some tools are more portable than others. As you mentioned teamviewer it is a good example. You can run it even without installation to gain basic functionality. For advanced features like autostart and login as well as running as a service for unattended remote control you have to install it. And for the way it integrates into the system it is very unlikely to run if you just copy the app directory to another computer.

The same goes for accessing applications over a network. Because the program wasn't set up by running it's setup it is likely to not work the way you want.

But again it is heavily depending on your program. Your best bet would be to just try it.

Hope that helps

Answer (score 0):

Except, what humble.adm1n said, the remote computer must:

1) be alowed for remote connection and remote launching of executables

2) allow things mentioned in point one to your account (account on remote computer, what you use to login there)